# How to create a role with specified arn with cloudformation in aws?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I want to create a role with specified arn by cloudformation in aws. But I don't know how to do it. Because we can't specify a name for the role in the template file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to an IAM role, this is not possible using CloudFormation.  CloudFormation will automatically generate a name for your role based on the stack name and the logical resource ID.  For example, `arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/myStackName-myRoleName-XXXXXXXXXXXXX`.